# Selecting an inner Element of the same outer Element type

Tags: jsoup

Works:

```
doc.select("table#mainTable table#newTable table")
```

Doesn't work:

```
doc.select("table#mainTable table#newTable").select("table")
```

Given an Element, such as `doc.select("table#mainTable table#newTable")`, how can I iterate on all of the nested `<table/>`'s?  I'm just getting the `table#newTable` returned back to me.

Comment: Please provide some html samples for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the selector that doesn't give you what you expect `doc.select("table#mainTable table#newTable").select("table")` is that it includes the parent table too.

**Example html**

```
<table id="mainTable">
  <tr>
    <td>First table</td>
    <td>
      <table id="newTable">
        <tr>
          <td>Second table</td>
          <td>
            <table id="lastone">
              <tr>
                <td>Third table</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The selector will return two elements
First element is the parent (that contains the table that you want)

```
<table id="newTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Second table</td>
      <td>
        <table id="lastone">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Third table</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the second element is the one you need

```
<table id="lastone"> 
 <tbody>
  <tr> 
   <td>Third table</td> 
  </tr> 
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Don't be alarmed by the tags that are missing from the example but are present in the result (`tbody`). They are added by jsoup's normalizer in order to give you a valid html in regards to the specification. So to conclude the answer, this query `doc.select("table#mainTable table#newTable table")` is fine. It will return `Elements` that will contain all the table elements that are children (bare in mind, not necessary immediate children) of a table with id `newTable` which in will be a child (again not necessary immediate) of a table with id `mainTable`.

**Example html**

```
<table id="mainTable">
  <tr>
    <td>First table</td>
    <td>
      <table id="newTable">
        <tr>
          <td>Second table</td>
          <td>
            <table id="lastone_1">
              <tr>
                <td>Third table</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="lastone_2">
              <tr>
                <td>Third table</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Code**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlStr);
Elements tables = doc.select("table#mainTable table#newTable table");

int i = 0;
for(Element l : tables) {
    System.out.println(i++ + " - " + l.attr("id"));
}
```

**Result**

```
0 - lastone_1
1 - lastone_2
```

**Update**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlStr);
Elements newTables = doc.select("table#mainTable table#newTable");

for(Element newTable : newTables) {
    Elements leafTables = newTable.children().select("table");
    for(Element leaf : leafTables) {
        System.out.println(leaf.attr("id"));
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having, is say I have some code that is passing an argument `foo` of type `Element` that was derived from the selector  `doc.select("table#mainTable table#newTable")` is there any way to get the child tables from `foo`? or do I have to go back and refactor things to pass in the original `doc` or perhaps `table#mainTable`

Comment: Yeap, you can. What you want are the children tables. Check my update.

Comment: That `newTable.children()` is the money shot :) thanks!